# How to use jelastic to deploy a MEAN app made with Angular & NestJS?

Tags: jelastic

I’m a developper, I’m new to jelastic, trying to understand how it works.

My app stack is not exactly a MEAN app (not mongo but SQL, not Express but NestJS).

- frontend Angular
- backend NestJS
- bdd mariadb

Locally, I’m using a docker-compose. All is working.

I’m using the [NestJS recipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static), so I need to build first the angular app, output the build in a directory where nest can build with itself and serve the static angular files all together.

What is the best way to set my stack with jelastic ?

1. Can I re-use my docker-compose ? (I believe not… so bad.)
2. Should I build docker images, push to docker-hub, pull in jelastic, etc. ?
3. How could I set up the environment to be the most close from my local environment ?

I’d prefer to use the deployment from git url, but I need to put some env variables, and I need to build from 2 repositories, with stages. Build Angular first, then Nest.

Any advices, best practices ?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use your docker-compose in Jelastic, since all of the docker related stuff is fully supported. But, the best practice is to use a certified [template](https://docs.jelastic.com/software-stacks-versions/) for each stack in case it is available and run each application in a separate container.
So, regarding your questions:
What is the best way to set my stack with jelastic ?

1. *Can I re-use my docker-compose ? (I believe not… so bad.)*

- Find application Docker Engine CE in Jelastic marketplace
  [image]
- Choose the option to use Docker-compose.
- In the open window you will see the example of repository hosted on GitHub with docker-compose in it. So, just follow the same way and you'll get all your dockers running inside.

2. *Should I build docker images, push to docker-hub, pull in jelastic, etc. ?*

Yes, you can do this way as well. Actually  all of the mentioned certified templates are done this way. Once you have pushed your images to Docker Hub you can find them in the Jelastic dashboard and install. For example, let's find the Nestjs one. Just click on New Environment in the Dashboard, then choose Docker, after that press Select Image, and finally search the Docker Hub for your image:
[image]
[image]
After the container is deployed it obtains an internal private IP  address, so all of your containers will be in one LAN. If necessary you can attach a public IP if your quota allows to make it reachable directly from the outside world instead of being exposed through the [Shared Load Balancer](https://docs.jelastic.com/shared-load-balancer/).

3. *How could I set up the environment to be the most close from my local environment ?*

To setup environment to be closest to your one you can try to follow the answer on your first question.
Since Jelastic PaaS provides an out-of-box integration of the fast, lightweight and highly scalable NodeJS application server. It is automatically supplied with numerous optimization and management tools to make the hosting process maximally convenient for developers. You may see this [tutorial](https://jelastic.com/blog/nodejs-hosting-paas/) to get better understanding of how you can host and deploy Node.js nested applications.
So I'd suggest you to follow this way -  create three environments:

- frontend Angular - use Node.Js template(contains [npm package manager](https://docs.jelastic.com/nodejs-package-managers/#node-package-manager))
- backend NestJS - use Node.Js template(contains [npm package manager](https://docs.jelastic.com/nodejs-package-managers/#node-package-manager))
- bdd mariadb - mariadb template.
  then any deployments can be done with integrated in Jelastic [CI/CD functionality](https://jelastic.com/blog/git-push-deploy-to-containers/) to deliver and deploy applications from GitHub. Such an approach will make your project more elastic.

Go to Marketplace and find